# MySql update with join from another table

Tags: mysql, join, field, concatenation

I added a column to my WorkSheetTransaction table and want to populate it with a name built from the Department table.  Both tables are already populated with the join field DepartmentId.

The following query runs ok but no rows are updated. Why not?

```
update WorkSheetTransactions
inner join Departments on WorkSheetTransactions.DepartmentId = Departments.DepartmentId 
set WorkSheetTransactions.DepartmentName = (Departments.GL_Account + '-' + Departments.DepartmentName)
```

I've tried many variations but I just can't see where I've gone wrong.  BTW, the join field is an integer in both tables and all the other 2 fields are var_chars.

Comment: Generally, it's best to handle issues of data display in application level code. Keep your data nice and normalised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mysql, you should use [`concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) to concatenate strings:

```
UPDATE WorkSheetTransactions
INNER JOIN Departments
ON WorkSheetTransactions.DepartmentId = Departments.DepartmentId 
SET WorkSheetTransactions.DepartmentName = concat(Departments.GL_Account, '-', Departments.DepartmentName)
```